# How is my ceiling rose/light switch functioning?? UK

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I recently changed a couple of ceiling roses for a newer ones that weren't grubby and yellow. I noticed something odd... in the fact there was only 2 cables going to them.

In previous houses I have lived at, there has always been 3. 2 which form part of the ring/circuit, and one goes to the switch. Im wondering, how on earth are the switch operating these lights?

Anyone have any ideas? I mean, the switches work, so something must be happening somewhere!

[image]

Comment: The picture seems to show a nick/bare wire where the brown wire comes out of the white tube.  I might just be seeing things, but would check.

Answer (score 2):

That rose looks correctly wired for and end-of-line situation. The usual 3 wires in a rose are loop in, loop out, and switch. loop out is optional as it is used to supply power to the next fitting. If all your light fittings are like this, then  either each light has it's own cable runnign back to the fuse box, or (more likely) the loop is connected in juction boxes above the ceiling. This could be because the current roses replaced fittings which did not have the necessary number of terminals for a switch connection.

Comment: Ah I thought that might be the case. I have replaced 2 like this now. They are all controlled by a single breaker so I assume they are looped via junction boxes in the ceiling. Thanks